# Displaying large text file in WPF without reading it into memory

Tags: wpf, large-files

I would like to be able to display a large text file in WPF - preferably as a FlowDocument (in order to style its appearance), but without reading the entire file into memory.

My idea would be to implement some sort of virtualized document = list of lines which however holds a limited set of lines in memory at a time. For example, if the file has 1,000,000 lines, the collection would initially only load lines 1-1000 into memory and when asked for lines beyond that would load another 100 lines while dropping the first 100, etc. This would need to be able to go in both directions, so when navigating back, the collection would need to re-read the first 100 lines, while dropping the last 100 lines from memory.
Furthermore, the collection would need to correctly reflect the total amount of lines - ideally up front, alternatively as it proceeds through the file.
(note: collection size 1000 and "page" size 100 are just examples).

How could this be displayed in a WPF control without the control itself storing all lines? I believe an ItemsControl with a virtualizing StackPanel could perhaps somehow do this, but it may be somewhat limited. Could FlowDocumentScrollViewer be customized to support this?

Comment: Not quite the same, but would FlowDocumentPageViewer be any use?